# What's the best way to troubleshoot an ASP.NET security exception?

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, web

I'm running into an error I just can't solve. I'm trying to host my website through an external hosting company.

Most reports consist of a server side permission issue but my hosting doesn't think that is the issue and won't budge on the idea.

Here is the message I'm getting:

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.

These are the suggestions I got send through from my hosting company:

Change to "On"

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

> Your connection is also referencing a database called
>   aspnet-Foundation-20151005115145.mdf however I cannot locate this
>   file, it's likely your database connection string is incorrect as its
>   trying to connect to a local database.

My database isn't active and is commented out in the Web.config file so this shouldn't be playing a part in the problem, right?

What's the best way to troubleshoot this issue?

Edit:

I have just added the following to the Web.config file to no avail.

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
</securityPolicy>
```

Comment: I think the reference to the database is the aspnet database it's referring to.  Have you seen this article on how to resolve security exception?  I hope it helps.  [link] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555466

Comment: Yes that was the first place I looked. The problem is I would need access to the server "machine.config file", since that code is stored on the server I cannot change it?